# Mysql pool connection with typescript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

I am working on project node with typescript , Now I need to connect with mysql database . Below is my code

```
import mysql  from 'mysql'
class MySql {
private client: '<any>';
constructor(){
        this.client = mysql.createPool({
            host     : 'localhost',
            user     : 'username',
            password : 'password',
            database : 'database'
        })
        this.client.connect()
        console.log('in constructor')
        console.log(this.client)
}
```

}

But it is giving me error , pool is not assignable to any type
so can you please help me how to overcome from this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the full error message/console output.

Comment: pool is not assignable to any type on client property ,same as I mention here, do you need screenshot ?

Comment: You made the type of client the literal string `<any>`

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as mysql from 'mysql2';
class MySql {
    private client: any = mysql.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'database'
    })
        constructor() {
        this.client.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            console.log('Error', err);
            console.log('connection info', connection);
        }
        }
    }
```